# Conditionally add headers to Ember data request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to add custom headers to an individual `this.store.find` search? I know this can be accomplished by adding custom headers to all outgoing requests using `$.ajaxSetup`, however I only need to add headers to a few searches - not every operation for a store.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization have a look at the doc first. Then about the answer of Eternal1 and your comment >> yes you can, as the headers is a property of your adapter and you can overwrite any of the methods required by an adapter in a custom adapter http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#toc_creating-an-adapter so set the header according to your requirement in those methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by creating a custom `DS.RESTAdapter`.

Say, you need specific headers on a model `Car`. You just do it like:

```
App.CarAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: {
    "API_KEY": "secret key",
    "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
  }
});
```

Voila, job done.

Comment: The header is only needed on certain operations. Is there a finer grained way of doing this?

Comment: This only adds headers only for requests associated with a `<ModelName>` in `<ModelName>Adapter` what's more specific or fine-grained than that?

Comment: I was tempted to downvote but held back because of the 2 years passed. I don't know why people found it hard to understand OP. Sometimes, e.g when query backend for api/cars/1 don't set headers so as to reverse proxy cache, but when querying for api/cars?model=benz send headers for personalized search. Been researching on this too, not yet found solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to add custom header only for GET operation